# Convert Arduino GSR values to microsiemens? (I should have it but I'm not sure)

Tags: arduino

I know that this question has been asked before, but I would like to have some clarifications.

I am buying this EDA sensor: https://store.plux.info/bitalino-sensors/11-electrodermal-activity-eda-sensor.html#/27-connectors-molex_sherlock
But I have to use it with Arduino. They say that the board returns a value between Range: 0-25μS (with VCC = 3.3V), which is exactly what I need.

However, if I connect to the Arduino and read the value of the Analog Pin, I will have a value between 0-1023. I think that I can convert this value to Volts by doing: 5/1024.

But, I need the value in microsiemens. On the Sensor Data Sheet they provide a formula for converting the data to μS: http://bitalino.com/datasheets/REVOLUTION_EDA_Sensor_Datasheet.pdf

[image]

If I understand, I should read the Analog Value of the Pin (e.g. 450).

Then do (450/2n * 3.3)/0.132

They also say:  The number of bits for each channel depends on the resolution of the Analog-to-Digital Converter (ADC);

I think that the ADC resolution for the Arduino uno is 10 bits. Does this sound correct? In which case I would have in this example: (450/1024 * 3.3)/0.132 which would give me 10.986 μS. Does this sound correct?

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: 2^10 is not 10245. And VCC of the Arduino Uno is not 3.3V.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I meant: 1024. 
As for the VCC, as far as I understand that is the power supply pin of the Arduino. Doesn't the Arduino uno have 2 types of power? 5V and 3.3V? In which case I could connect the sensor to the 3.3 as they seem to suggest.

If that is not the case, then what is the VCC of the  Arduino Uno?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No the Vcc in the formula is input power of arduino uno: 5V.

They say that the board returns a value between Range: 0-25μS (with VCC = 3.3V).

If the boards measures EDA of 25μS, it will output 3.3V. So EDA(25) = output(3.3) / 0.132

From the arduino point of view, you get the voltage with formula:

```
value(V) = value(ADC numeric value) /1024 * 5V
```

Comment: I see, you are right. Thank you very much for your clarification.

So, if I want the value in Microsiemens can I just use the same formula that they show on the data sheet, but replace the 3.3 with 5.
That is: ((AnalogPinValue/1024) * 5)/0.132?

The only difference would be that I would have an output between 0-37.88 rather then 0-25, right?

Comment: yes you can use the same formula with 5. On the other hand the board is powered with 3.3V, so it will output 3.3V max. So arduino wont measure as high as 1024 (5V), it will measure 676 (3.3V) at max.